# Struts2 action called twice on jsp load

Tags: struts2

Am using struts 2.3.x, when calling action, it executes and loads resultant jsp. After jsp loads same action method getting executed. Am not using any interceptors.

Comment: *Can anybody help me to solve this issue?* Without code? Sure, we're on it, just wait

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Because it's called again?